# There are at most three walks of length 4 between any two distinct vertices of the graph G?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

The following adjacency matrix given by A represents a graph called G:

$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix} \right] $$

I'm asked to consider whether the following statement is true or false:
"There are at most three walks of length 4 between any two distinct vertices of G."

Here's what I've done so far:

I'm trying to use the following theorem:
The number of walks of length k from v_i to v_j is equal to the (i,j)-th entry of the matrix A^k

I've taken $$A^4 = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix} \right] $$

So I've got v1 & v2 has one walk and v3 & v4 has one walk.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a correct value of $A^4$

Comment: Your $A^4$ is wrong; what do you get for $A^2$?

Comment: Have you tired to draw the graph?

Comment: I've taken the entries of A^4 mod 2

Comment: why did you take them $\bmod 2 $? You should leave them as is, taking them $\bmod 2$ may be suitable for some other problems, but in this instance we lose the information we need !

Comment: I thought this is what you do, as the entries in A are all 0s and 1s

Comment: Sure, but when you take higher powers you get larger values, and reducing them $\bmod 2$ does not do what we want it to.

Answer (score 1):

One has $A^4= \begin{pmatrix}
2  & 3  & 0  & 0 \\ 
3  & 5  & 0  & 0 \\ 
0  & 0  & 5  & 3 \\ 
0  & 0  & 3  & 2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$

As one can see no value greater than $4$ lies outside the diagonal.

This is a possible proof.

Comment: Ah, hence making the statement true?

Comment: Yes the statement is true, the matrix raised to the fourth power contains the information we need, but we need to calculate it correctly !

Comment: good luck with your homework.

Comment: You can probably do things along the lines of this question though: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124116/maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-planar-graph

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It was my pleasure.